# TypeScript: Using Type Parameters in Generic Constraints

Tags: javascript, typescript

"[Using Type Parameters in Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints)" in the TypeScript site shows the example code below. But the following error occurred:

> 'Type 'U[keyof U]' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof U]'.   Type 'U'
>   is not assignable to type 'T'.'

```
function copyFields<T extends U, U>(target: T, source: U): T {
    for (let id in source) {
        target[id] = source[id];
    }
    return target;
}
let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
copyFields(x, { b: 10, d: 20 });
```

In fact, this does not run in the Playground.  What is wrong with the code?

Comment: It's surprising that the code in the docs doesn't compile. I'd recommend filing an issue in the https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook repo about this

Comment: I posted the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/475) and got a reply.

Answer (score 4):

It makes sense that `U` is not assignable to `T` since the object satisfying `U` could have additional fields that `T` doesn't have:

```
interface Foo { foo: number; }
interface Bar extends Foo { bar: number; }
interface Bar2 extends Foo { bar: string; }

function assign<T extends U, U>(b: U): T {
    const returnVal: T = b;  // error: Type 'U' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    return returnVal;
}

const bar2: Bar2 = { foo: 7, bar: "happy" };
assign<Bar, Foo>(bar2);
```

So, since `U` isn't assignable to `T`, there's no way we can guarantee that a specific `U[keyof U]` is assignable to `T[keyof U]`.

(I'm not 100% confident in this explanation, but it seems to make sense to me.)

---

However, by modifying how you type things, you can write a version of `copyFields` that works as intended, [like this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12793#issuecomment-266055843):

```
function copyFields<T, K extends keyof T>(target: T, source: Pick<T, K>) {
    for (let id in source) {
        target[id] = source[id];
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I understood your explanation.  And revised code works fine.